# how to replace ObjectId in JavaScript with Epoch Time

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, timestamp, objectid

How do I iterate through a JSON string and replace every [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/object-id/) into [Unix Epoch time](http://www.epochconverter.com/) for further processing?

What I know:
You get the first 8 chars from an objectId with:

```
subStrObjectId = objectId.substring(0, 8);
```

*5668d142a54cc4960b55ea19 --> 5668D142*

and convert these from hexadecimal into an Int value (epoch time in milliseconds):

```
subStrObjectIdInDec = parseInt(subStrObjectId, 16);
```

*5668D142 (hex) --> 1449709890 (dec)*

my Json string:

```
myJsonString = [
    [
        {"_id":"5668d142a54cc4960b55ea19","cid":10851045,"temp":25.4},
        {"_id":"5668d14ea54cc4960b55ea1a","cid":10850909,"temp":24.9}
    ],
    [
        {"_id":"5668d14fa54cc4960b55ea1b","cid":10851045,"hum":37.9},
        {"_id":"5668d3108c8cda92074b7ec9","cid":10850909,"hum":39.6}
    ],
    [
        {"_id":"5668d3198c8cda92074b7ecb","cid":10851045,"lux":34},
        {"_id":"5668d31e8c8cda92074b7ecc","cid":10850909,"lux":68}
    ]
];
```

Comment: what is your question? what you are doing seems ok.

Comment: how do I iterate through this json example string "myJsonString" and replace all the objectIds with the correct epoch time? how do I write such function?

Comment: I posted an answer, if that answers your question, consider marking it as the answer for future visitors.

Comment: Hello Amir and user3100115, both of you: thank you. Your solutions did solve my problem!
@Amir, I'm from a different timezone, I had to go sleep. Patience

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write what you know as a function:

```
function convert(id) {
  return parseInt(id.substring(0, 8), 16);
}
```

You can easily iterate over your objects and run your function on the objects.

I'd prefer functional-style javascript:

```
var data = myJsonString.map(function (array) {
  return array.map(function (item) {
    item.time = convert(item._id);
    return item;
  })
})

console.log(data);
```

But you can go iterative with loops as well:

```
for (var i=0;i<myJsonString.length;i++) {
  for (var j=0;j<myJsonString[i].length;j++) {
    myJsonString[i][j].time = convert(myJsonString[i][j]._id);
  }
}
console.log(myJsonString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`getTimestamp()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/ObjectId.getTimestamp/#ObjectId.getTimestamp)  to return the timestamp portion of the [`ObjectId()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/object-id/#core-object-id-class) as a Date.

```
myJsonString.map(
    function(element) {
        return element.map(function(doc) {
            doc.timestamp = ObjectId(doc._id).getTimestamp(); 
            doc._id = ObjectId(doc._id); // Only if you want to convert your _id string to valid Objectid
            return doc;
        })
    }
);
```

Which yields:

```
[       
    [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5668d14fa54cc4960b55ea1b"),
                    "cid" : 10851045,
                    "hum" : 37.9,
                    "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-12-10T01:11:43Z")
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5668d3108c8cda92074b7ec9"),
                    "cid" : 10850909,
                    "hum" : 39.6,
                    "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-12-10T01:19:12Z")
            }
    ],
    [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5668d3198c8cda92074b7ecb"),
                    "cid" : 10851045,
                    "lux" : 34,
                    "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-12-10T01:19:21Z")
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5668d31e8c8cda92074b7ecc"),
                    "cid" : 10850909,
                    "lux" : 68,
                    "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-12-10T01:19:26Z")
            }
    ]
]
```